# ElasticSearch NotFoundError

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to using elasticsearch as a database for my python application. I wanted to create a indice in elasticsearch for my application.

But it keeps returning me NotFoundError, so I tried fetching the list of indices, even that gives not FoundError.

```
def create_indexes(self):

        try:

            client = Elasticsearch(['{}'.format(self.domain)], http_auth=('username','{}'.format(ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD)), port=9243)
            print(client)

        except Exception as E:
            print("\n\n\n\n......CONNECTION ERROR", E)

        print("\n\n\n\n\n.......CREATING A INDEX HERE...............")

        # get client
        try:
            # result = client.indices.create(index='vehicle', body={"key": "val"}, request_timeout=30)

            result = client.indices.get_alias("*")

            print("\n\n\n......RESULT", result)
        except Exception as E:
            print("\n\n\n [ERROR IN CREATING THE INDEX]", E)


        return True
```

Where my domain is like: `https://xxx.region-zone.gcp.cloud.es.io`

The error I am getting is:

```
[ERROR IN CREATING THE INDEX] NotFoundError(404, 'Not Found', 'Not Found')
```

I am quite not able to get is it because the indices are not there or because it has not connected properly to the cluster. Is there any way I can check I am connected to the cluster instance also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there was a problem w/ connecting to the cluster it would've thrown `CREATING A INDEX HERE`. Has it? What did `print(client)` above return?

You could also try printing `client.cat.indices()` and if that fails too, you've got a (connection) problem.